# Can't check LongAdder value in if-statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I want my program to do something different if the button has been pressed the second or third time. For that I tried to count the clicks which worked just fine(thanks to this forum) but now I fail to test if the number is e.g 1. The error message says it is an invalid operator but what could I do else?

```
LongAdder numButtonClicks = new LongAdder();
tellingIntroButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    numButtonClicks.increment();

    if (numButtonClicks == 0) {
        //some code
    }
});
```

Comment: you can't compare `LongAdder` with 0 instead you can use `if (numButtonClicks.intValue() == 0) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your counter is now an instance of `LongAdder` (which means you're dealing with an object), you can't really compare it that way (using the equals operator with a scalar).

You can however get its `long` value and compare it with another `long`.

```
if (numButtonClicks.longValue() == 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Please refer to the `LongAdder` API documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html#longValue--).